# VB script: Message while Unzipping a file

Tags: vbscript

I am using the below vb script to un-zip the files, so while un-zipping is going on, i am seeing a pop up messgae(Copying/extracting), is there any way to get rid of popup message?

```
FileToGetUnZipped = "InstallDir\UI_Files.zip"
DestPathForUnzippedFile = "InstallDir\system"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If Not objFSO.FolderExists(DestPathForUnzippedFile) Then
    objFSO.CreateFolder(DestPathForUnzippedFile)
End If

UnZipFile FileToGetUnZipped, DestPathForUnzippedFile

Sub UnZipFile(strArchive, DestPathForUnzippedFile)
    Set objApp = CreateObject( "Shell.Application" )

    Set objArchive = objApp.NameSpace(strArchive).Items()
    Set objDest = objApp.NameSpace(DestPathForUnzippedFile)

    objDest.CopyHere objArchive
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [CopyHere](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787866%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method takes a second argument which can be a combination of various options, including

> (4)
>
> > Do not display a progress dialog box.

However, I have not had much success on getting many of these options to work reliably - I think it varies by Windows version as much as anything else.

As a side note, I think you may have issues with the `CopyHere` method being asynchronous - your script may complete before `CopyHere` does, which may kill the copying process.